# IdentityServer4 well known configuration generates invalid url schemas with double backslashes

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, amazon-linux

My IdentityServer4 instance returns deformed schema for the urls in the reponse of the well-known configs. Here is the response that I get from 
http://www.server.meetcorepoint.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

```
{"issuer":"http://\\www.server.meetcorepoint.com","jwks_uri":"http://\\www.server.meetcorepoint.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks","authorization_endpoint":"http://\\www.server.meetcorepoint.com/connect/authorize","token_endpoint":"http://\\www.server.meetcorepoint.com/connect/token","userinfo_endpoint":"http://\\www.server.meetcorepoint.com/connect/userinfo","end_session_endpoint":"http://\\www.server.meetcorepoint.com/connect/endsession","check_session_iframe":"http://\\www.server.meetcorepoint.com/connect/checksession","revocation_endpoint":"http://\\www.server.meetcorepoint.com/connect/revocation","introspection_endpoint":"http://\\www.server.meetcorepoint.com/connect/introspect","frontchannel_logout_supported":true,"frontchannel_logout_session_supported":true,"backchannel_logout_supported":true,"backchannel_logout_session_supported":true,"scopes_supported":["openid","profile","api1","offline_access"],"claims_supported":["sub","name","family_name","given_name","middle_name","nickname","preferred_username","profile","picture","website","gender","birthdate","zoneinfo","locale","updated_at"],"grant_types_supported":["authorization_code","client_credentials","refresh_token","implicit","password"],"response_types_supported":["code","token","id_token","id_token token","code id_token","code token","code id_token token"],"response_modes_supported":["form_post","query","fragment"],"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_basic","client_secret_post"],"subject_types_supported":["public"],"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256"],"code_challenge_methods_supported":["plain","S256"]}
```

Here is the mvc client http://www.mvc.meetcorepoint.com and when I click to authenticate with the idsr4 the client throws exception `Unable to parse host name` and fails to do authentication because it can't parse the urls.

Note the `\\` appended to the schema in each url of the response. All urls are invalid. Both the idsr4 and the mvc client are hosted on Amazon Linux. The two projects that I use are both from the official sample projects on GitHub https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/5_HybridFlowAuthenticationWithApiAccess 
I am using version 2.0.4 of dotnet core. 
On localhost the idsr4 works as expected and returns the appropriate response without additional double backslashes.
**What is causing the wrong url schemas and how to fix this ?** Feel free to test the identity server yourself on the live servers.

Comment: Is it behind a proxy or load balancer? Could that be manipulating the host name somehow? Also, why is it not running under HTTPS if it's exposed to the world?

Comment: I will apply https later on the production servers, since right now I am just trying to host it, but thanks for the reminder! 
And yes, you hit straight to the point. I am running the app behind nginx and when I have copied the configuration from web somehow it prepended backslash to the `Upgrade` and `Host` headers so instead of having `proxy_set_header Host $host;` I had `proxy_set_header Host \$host;` 
Thank you so much! I had spent 9 hours trying to fix this. I've never had much luck with copy-pasting :)